# kubernetes network policy to disable all internet connections for specific namespace on AWS - EKS

Tags: security, kubernetes, containers, amazon-eks

I wanna deny the container from accessing the public internet.

After a long research, I found [this example: DENY external egress traffic](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes/blob/master/14-deny-external-egress-traffic.md) :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: foo-deny-external-egress
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foo
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - ports:
    - port: 53
      protocol: UDP
    - port: 53
      protocol: TCP
   to:
    - namespaceSelector: {}
```

But it does not work. Indeed, I ran `wget https://google.com` and I got a positive response.
Any hint is apperciated

Comment: what is network plugin type used on your cluster !!

Comment: good question! This is an AWS managed service  (EKS). Anyway, the cluster was provisioned from this  terraform module  : https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/

Comment: Have you tried a test with a basic block all network policy `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all-egress
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress` i.e exclude the DNS port 53 as well??

Answer (score 3):

The network policy works fine on calico.
**Network Policy has no effect on cluster using flannel network plugin**.

> As mentioned on this [link](https://github.com/coreos/flannel) Flannel is focused on networking. For network policy, other projects such as Calico can be used.

**Network policy blocks traffic as expected on  cluster using calico**

I have two clusters one using flannel and one using calico and test works as expected on calico.

Logs :

```
$ kubectl apply -f networkpolicy.yaml
networkpolicy.networking.k8s.io/foo-deny-external-egress created


ubuntu@calico-master-1:~$ kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sleep 3600
pod/busybox created


$ kubectl get networkpolicy
NAME                       POD-SELECTOR   AGE
foo-deny-external-egress   run=busybox    30m

$ kubectl exec -it busybox -- /bin/sh
/ # wget https://google.com
Connecting to google.com (74.125.193.102:443)
wget: can't connect to remote host (74.125.193.102): Connection timed out
```

**On cluster using Flannel creating network policy has no effect**

```
ubuntu@k8s-flannel:~$ kubectl exec -it busybox -- /bin/sh
/ # curl https://google.com
/bin/sh: curl: not found
/ # wget https://google.com
Connecting to google.com (216.58.207.238:443)
wget: note: TLS certificate validation not implemented
Connecting to www.google.com (172.217.20.36:443)
saving to 'index.html'
index.html           100% |*************************************************************************************************************************************************| 12498  0:00:00 ETA
'index.html' saved
```

Apply policy

```
$ kubectl apply -f networkpolicy.yaml
networkpolicy.networking.k8s.io/foo-deny-external-egress created

$ kubectl get networkpolicy
NAME                       POD-SELECTOR   AGE
foo-deny-external-egress   run=busybox    32m
```

We can still get to network outside as **network policy does not work on flannel**.

```
$ kubectl exec -it busybox -- /bin/sh
/ # wget https://google.com
Connecting to google.com (172.217.22.174:443)
wget: note: TLS certificate validation not implemented
Connecting to www.google.com (172.217.20.36:443)
saving to 'index.html'
index.html           100% |*************************************************************************************************************************************************| 12460  0:00:00 ETA
'index.html' saved
```

Comment: I installed [calico on the eks cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/calico.html). But still no effect.

Comment: provide please list of all your pods. I feel you had already cni and just installed 2nd one. `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`. [Add Calico on flight](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v1.5/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/) is not the same as apply 1 yaml.

Answer (score 1):

The default CNI on EKS doesn't support network policies. You should either

- Install calico as described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/calico.html or
- Use security group policies for pods https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/security-groups-for-pods.html